# How to remove the row of the data table using ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

I want to delete the row of the table after the ajax call. Here my code:

```
function getResultsMsr(action, msrDel) {
if(action == 'search') {
$('#example').dataTable( {
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": "testing_ajax.php",
"columnDefs": [ 
 {   
 "aTargets":[7],  // this your column of action
 "mData": null, 
 "mRender": function(data, type, full){
 var rowId= full[6];
return '<td id="row'+msrDel+'"><a href="javascript: void(0);"  onclick="removeRow('+rowId+');" >Delete</a>
  }
  }
 ]
 } );
```

Here is my delete function what I have tried for delete the row :

```
function removeRow(msrDel){
var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
$.ajax({
url: 'getResult.php',
type: 'POST',
data: "id="+msrDel
}).done(function(result_data){
parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});

});
return false;
}
```

Comment: what is `$(this)` in your `removeRow(msrDel)` function?

Comment: i guess kinda the id of the row he wants deleted

Comment: Do you want to delete a `<tr>` (row) or `<td>` (column)?

Comment: The problem is that `$(this)` probably isn't a reference to the row that you're trying to remove, you can check this by doing `console.log($(this));`  If you call fnDraw(); on the table instead, although obviously this involves a db call.

Comment: I want to remove the whole row after the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

function removeRow(msrDel){

```
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getResult.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                        formName:'afscpMsr',
                        action:'delete',
                        delmsr: msrDel
                    }
                }).done(function(result_data){
                //  parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                    oTable.fnDeleteRow( $('#example tbody tr:eq(0)')[0] );
                });

            return false;
            }
```

Comment: Surely that will just delete the first row?